# C# visual studio using AddtableRow to add rows to a table and am getting an overload error but the field count is correct

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, refresh

In this system one program creates table records and a second updates them.  I want the update program to see the new records.  See lots of queries/responses to this but so far none have worked for me.  One solution was to clear and reload the dataset table.  The following code recreates the dataset but I can't include the auto incremented primary key bookid.  If it is there I get an overload error even thought the field count is correct.  If I remove it the dataset.booking table is loaded but the bookid values are wrong negative numbers) and I can't update the dataset.booking table as it does not match the database table.

```
tclDataSet3.booking.AcceptChanges();
tclDataSet3.booking.Clear();
bookingBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

var bkas1 = tcdb.bookings.Where(b => b.approvalStatus == 1);
foreach (booking bk in bkas1)
    tclDataSet3.booking.AddbookingRow(  
        (int)bk.bookId, 
        (int)bk.bookYear,
        (int)bk.bookMonth,
        (int)bk.bookDay,
        (int)bk.workOrder,
        (int)bk.customerNum,
        bk.firstName,
        bk.lastName,
        bk.vehicle,
        (int)bk.serviceCar,
        bk.repairType,
        (bool)bk.isCompleted,
        (bool)bk.isPickedUp,
        bk.outYear,
        bk.outMonth,
        bk.outDay,
        (bool)bk.isDeleted,
        (int)bk.isUpdated,
        bk.bookingTime,
        (int)bk.approvalStatus);
```

Program requirements:
display datagridview of dataset.booking table where as_code = 1
updates rows in datagrideview to change as_code = 2
remove updated rows from datagridview (bookingBindingSource.RemoveCurrent(); works well)

Refresh datagridview to see all dataset.booking table rows where as_code = 1

Currently the refresh only sees existing records in the datagrideview.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your as_code is doing here. You did not present a minimal reproducible use case. If it were me, I would use the database query to get the datatable, and then bind it to the datagridview.DataSource. Then synchronize with the database through the update statement. I have seen the type conversion in your code, which may cause a mismatch with the database type, resulting in failure to update. Please show your database type by the way. Tell me what you want to do in more colloquial terms.

Comment: I am trying to update a dataGridView to display new rows added via a different program.  Created a "Refresh" button but cannot figure out how to get the dataGridView to see the new rows.  I see the new rows in the base table but the dataGridView bound to a dataset does not see them unless I close and reopen the program.

Comment: Having no success in getting the bound data to refresh when it is updated externally to the program (while the program is running).  I unbound the data and wrote my own refresh routines.  Works now.

Comment: Based on your comment, I have updated my answer. Please mark it if it helps you. This can help someone with the same problem.

Comment: Do you have time to check my answer? Or you could answer it yourself. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I decided to rewrite the code to manually build the dataGridView rather than use any data binding.  I created a subroutine to clear the dataGridView, read the base table and rebuild the dataGridView.

Comment: You could mark it as the answer.